# QGIS2WEB Zoom to Selection

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis2web

I'm working on a project and think that having a function that works similarly to how the 'Zoom to search address' function. That is, when using qgis2web Leaflet with the "Add address search" box ticked, any address that is searched will automatically zoom to fit the web map export. Is it possible to modify the plugin or an existing function that I'm simply missing that would do the same Zoom to fit when you select a feature?

Comment: Explain yourself better, would you like to have a button that, if active, allows you to click on the features and perform an extension zoom on them?